# Point.Empty.Equals(Point.Empty) == false // why?

Tags: geo, jts, nettopologysuite

Using NetTopologySuite, these expressions are false:

```
Point.Empty.Equals(Point.Empty); // false    
Polygon.Empty.Equals(Polygon.Empty); // false
```

Debugging shows that this behavior is implemented by

```
    // Geometry
    public IntersectionMatrix Relate(IGeometry g)
    {        
        return RelateOp.Relate(this, g); // Point.Empty, Point.Empty
    }

    // IntersectionMatrix
    public bool IsEquals(Dimension dimensionOfGeometryA, Dimension dimensionOfGeometryB)
    {
        if (dimensionOfGeometryA != dimensionOfGeometryB)
            return false;

        return IsTrue(_matrix[(int)Location.Interior, (int)Location.Interior]) &&
               _matrix[(int)Location.Interior, (int)Location.Exterior] == Dimension.False &&
               _matrix[(int)Location.Boundary, (int)Location.Exterior] == Dimension.False &&
               _matrix[(int)Location.Exterior, (int)Location.Interior] == Dimension.False &&
               _matrix[(int)Location.Exterior, (int)Location.Boundary] == Dimension.False;
    }
```

I wonder what the reason behind this is. Presumably this behavior occurs in related libraries (jts, GEOS) as well and I also assume there is a justification known by geo-algebra insiders. Can someone explain?

Comment: This question would be better suited for gis.stackexchange.com!